# Access a file object from JSON string using php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want to access my file object from the JSON string as shown below

```
stdClass Object(
[data] => stdClass Object
    (
        [testType] => Aptitude
        [testCourse] => Java Developer
        [testDate] => 2016-02-04
        [testDuration] => 10
        [testStartTime] => 04:43
        [testEndTime] => 5:00
        [testQuestions] => 10
        [testFile] => stdClass Object
        (
        )
    )
)
```

This JSON is constructed by my angular function.I am not sure that testFile object really contains the file uploaded by me,but when I do log into my js file  get

File[object File]

Please suggest me a solution for this.
Thank you..

Comment: Well unless you edited the contents of `[testFile']` out of your question. It is an empty object. Check the code that creates the JSON data structure, the error is probably there

Comment: Then what  should come under testFile object according to you,because I constructed the testFile attribute in the same way as other atributes and also js shows me the File Object

Comment: I have no idea what **should be in that object** my point is **it is empty, devoid of content, lacking in any inner meaning**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if my answer is right. But if you want to access inside the JSON string using php, you can use "(object)" before your $_POST.

```
$variable = (object)$_POST['JSON-Object'];
```

You can access the values of JSON string using foreach in php.
I hope it helps.

Comment: $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));                               $testFile = $data->data->testFile;                                                                 I am getting like this

Comment: i have never tried it. but you may try put the (object) instead of the json_decode. because i have tried the json_decode, sometimes it does not work

Comment: If a `json_decode()` does not work then there is an issue with the JSON string. Use `json_last_error()` and/or `json_last_error_msg()` when it fails to get an error code and/or and error message

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have json string? Check it and then try to use json_decode(_your_json_string_) function. It will return you an object.